# Why setinterval brings back an integer (newbie)

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
function myTimer() {
   return new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
}

setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);
```

why myTimer when called alone returns string as expected, but when called through setInterval it returns an integer?

Comment: You can recognize an interval with that integer, and use it to stop the interval with [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval).

Comment: it's `setInterval` that is returning an integer ... returning a value in a function called in setInterval/setTimeout is an exercise in futility as the returned value is not accessible

Comment: To go into detail, setInterval returns a kind of 'id' so you can clear it later. The return value of myTimer just gets swallowed by the timeout. So the two returns are compeltely unrelated. the new Date is only within scope inside the setInterval fn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The returned timeoutID is a numeric, non-zero value which identifies the timer created by the call to setInterval(); this value can be passed to Window.clearInterval() to cancel the timeout.

Details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval